# Why does it store or allocate memory for super class variables, in sub class object?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

In the following code-

```
class Mammal {
  String name = "furry ";
  String makeNoise() { 
    return "generic noise";
 }
}

class Zebra extends Mammal {
    String name = "stripes ";
    String makeNoise() { 
        return "bray"; 
    }
}

public class ZooKeeper {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       new ZooKeeper().go();
   }

   void go() {
      Mammal m = new Zebra();
      System.out.println(m.name + m.makeNoise());

      Zebra z = new Zebra();
      System.out.println(z.name + z.makeNoise());
   }
}
```

Both objects (`m` and `z`), if I see in debug windows of eclipse, contain both values of `name` variable (`furry` and `stripes`).

I do understand that in polymorphism, generic method of super class can be used by sub class as well. But why does sub class object stores values of super class variables as well, even in case of hiding. Is there any use of this?

Comment: There isn't a subclass object and super class object. There's just *one* object. When you do `new Zebra()` you get *one* `Zebra` (that itself is also a `Mammal`). You don't get one `Zebra` object and another `Mammal` object.

Comment: It's because you have declared `name` twice: `Zebra.name` "hides" `Mammal.name` - it's not the same variable. Remove the declaration from Zebra and put the assignment into the constructor of Mammal to use the same variable (not just one with the same name). There is only one object, a Zebra that is also a Mammal, but there is no stand-alone Mammal object somewhere, floating around.

Comment: Where else is it going to store them? Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: As a general rule, if a class defines a field that a subclass can access, the subclass *should not* redefine the field. It's just a Really Bad Idea. Primarily what you're seeing is there to make **private** fields work properly. Redefining non-private fields in a subclass is asking for a world of hurt. (Of course, if Joe writes `Mammal` and Mary writes `Zebra` and at some point Joe adds a field to `Mammal` that happens to conflict with one that Mary used in `Zebra`, there's nothing Mary can do about that. Which is one reason for making all fields private.)

> But why does sub class object stores values of super class variables as well, even in case of hiding.

The key here is to remember that fields are not polymorphic, just methods. So there *have* to be two `name` fields in the object (one from `Mammal` and one from `Zebra`), because code using a `Mammal`-typed reference needs to see the `Mammal` `name`, whereas code using the `Zebra`-typed reference needs to see the `Zebra` `name`.

That's why your code shows "furry bray" and then "stripes bray". You get "furry bray" via `m` because accessing `name` on `m` (a `Mammal`-typed variable) accesses `Mammal`'s `name` (not polymorphic), giving you "furry". But then you call the method `makeNoise` using `m` and get back `"bray"`, because the method that gets called is the one on `Zebra` (polymorphic). Then you do it again with `z` (a `Zebra`-typed reference) and see "stripes bray" because `z` accesses `Zebra`'s `name`, not `Mammal`'s.

---

The next question you might have is: If we change `makeNoise` in both classes to:

```
String makeNoise() { 
    return this.name;
}
```

why does `ZooKeeper`'s code

```
  Mammal m = new Zebra();
  System.out.println(m.name + m.makeNoise());

  Zebra z = new Zebra();
  System.out.println(z.name + z.makeNoise());
```

give us "furry stripes" from `m` and `stripes stripes` from `z`?

It's the same reason, just a different presentation of it. `m.name` accesses `name` from a `Mammal`-typed reference, and so sees `Mammal`'s `name` (not polymorphic). `m.makeNoise` calls **`Zebra`'s** `makeNoise` method (polymorphic), and inside `Zebra`'s `makeNoise`, `this` has the type `Zebra` even though we called it from a `Mammal`-typed `m` (and so `this.name` uses `Zebra`'s `name`). The fact that Zebra's `makeNoise` is used there, and the fact that `this` within `Zebra` code is typed `Zebra` are both key to polymorphism in Java.

Let's take it further: What if `Zebra` doesn't define `makeNoise` at all?

```
class Mammal {
    String name = "furry ";
    String makeNoise() { 
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Zebra extends Mammal {
    String name = "stripes ";
}
```

Now we get "furry furry" from `m` and "stripes furry" from `z`. And the reason for it is the same as above: The type of the reference determines which field is used, and in `Mammal` code (`makeNoise`), `this` has the type `Mammal`. So even though we called `makeNoise` using `z`, since `Zebra` has no `makeNoise`, `Mammal`'s is called, so the reference that looks up `name` has the type `Mammal`.

> Is there any use of this?

It's **crucial** to classes working properly, particularly in the case of private fields. `Mammal` code doesn't have to worry about a subclass coming along and redefining its fields. You could have a 10-deep class hierarchy, with each class defining its own `name`, and that's fine, each level's code works with the `name` it defines.