# How memory allocates to superclass and subclass members when we create object of subclass using superclass reference variable

Tags: java

```
class A {
    int y = 10;

    void m1() {
        System.out.println("This is M1");
        int b = 20;
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;

    void m1() {
        System.out.println("This is M2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        System.out.println(a.y);
        a.m1();
    }

}
```

What will be the memory allocation chart/diagram for this?

Comment: What do *you* think? Why? Where is thevunclseity/question that you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does it store or allocate memory for super class variables, in sub class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666659/why-does-it-store-or-allocate-memory-for-super-class-variables-in-sub-class-obj)

Answer (score 0):

- `new B`:

  - B is allocated, size of B (includes size of A) all field defaulted
  - constructor of `B()`:

    - super.A() called; recurses:

      - constructor of `A()`:
      - super.Object() called; recurses
      - all initialized fields of A are assigned: `A.this.y = 10;`
      - rest of the A constructor statements is executed
    - all initialized fields of B are assigned: `B.this.x = 10; B.this.y = 20;`
    - rest of the B constructor statements is executed

So the allocation is primarily done in the **`new`**.

The allocation done in the constructor and field initialisations can be illustrated in the next corner cast (to be avoided):

```
class A {
    A() {
        init(); // VERY BAD STYLE
    }
    protected void init() {
    }
}

class B extends A {
    String s1 = null;
    String s2;
    String s3 = "s3";
    String s4;
    String s5 = "s5";
    B() {
        // s1: null, s2: null, s3: null, s4: null, s5: null
        // super() called, calling init()
        // s1: "i1", s2: "i2", s3: "i3", s4: null, s5: null
        // field initialisation:
        // - s1 = null; s3 = "s3"; s5 = "s5";
        // s1: null, s2: "i2", s3: "i3", s4: null, s5: "s5"
        // remaining code of constructor
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        // s1: null, s2: null, s3: null, s4: null, s5: null
        s1 = "i1";
        s2 = "i2";
        s3 = "i3";
        // s1: "i1", s2: "i2", s3: "i3", s4: null, s5: null
    }
}
```

The above shows the starting life times of fields, and the unexpected moments if someone ever **uses overridable methods in a constructor**.

It also shows that in the constructor of A the super fields already exist (with default values `null, 0, false, 0.0, ...`).